# How to call firestore getDocument within a cloud function and send it's response back to the client using cloud function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to javascript/nodeJS. I'm trying to implement a http firebase cloud function which receives userID in it's body. Once it is received I need to call the firestore getDocument function and get it's corresponding data, manipulate with these data and send back to the client in the http cloud function response.

My code is as follows, I'm getting an empty response in the Postman. However I could notice in my server logs, following statement within my firestore getDocument prints the correct data.

```
console.log('Document data:', user);
```

However when I print the same data in my http cloud function it is empty.

```
console.log('User data:', user);
```

According to my understanding even though firestore gets the actual data, http cloud function send it's response before retrieving these actual data which result in an empty response.

Appreciate your insight. Thanks in advance!

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
let db = admin.firestore();

var getRequestedUserDetails = function (userId, db) {
  var user;
  var cityRef = db.collection('users').doc(userId);
  var getDoc = cityRef.get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
        return user;
      } else {
        user = doc.data();
        console.log('Document data:', user);
        return user;
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting document', err);
      throw new Error('Error getting document', err);
    });

    return user;
}

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  if (request.method !== "POST") {
    response.status(400).send('Invalid HTTP Request');
    return;
  }

  userId = request.body.userId;

  var user = getRequestedUserDetails(userId, db);
  console.log('User data:', user);

  response.send(user);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`get()` is asynchronous and returns immediately with a promise that resolves some unknown time later with the results of the query.  Your function `getRequestedUserDetails` is returning `user` before it ever gets defined.  Instead, perhaps your function could also return the promise that resolves when the results of the query, and the caller could use `then()` to receive its results and send the response.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Appreciate if u could show how to return a promise that resolves ones the data is retrieved.

Comment: There are a bunch of tutorials on how to use promises, especially in Cloud Functions.  You could start here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/functions-and-firebase